# Disable actors in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

After a series of transformations of my stage (fadout some stuff etc.) I have to disable several actors from catching any input. In swing I just would disable them but how can I disable an actor in libgdx for getting any touche input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it might be actor.setTouchable() you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, is there a way to disable the children but not the parent? I have a scrollpane which is disable too?

Comment: could you loop through parent .getChildren() and set them individually?